# Simple way to grant IAM policy for READONLY to view everything?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For example say I have an auditor that needs to look at everything in my AWS account, but only look.

Is there a built-in IAM policy for READ ONLY access to everything?

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#aws-managed-policies) called `ReadOnlyAccess` provides read-only access to all AWS services and resources.

If you want to provide read access to other resources, for example the file system on a running EC2 instance or the data stored in a SQL Server DB, then those would be on a case-by-case basis, outside of IAM.